# Single install or multisite?

Tags: multisite

I'm at a bit of an impasse trying to satisfy this client's requirements.  Long story short, they would like an overall site that certain people can access and modify, plus a blog with a completely different look and feel.  Their current site was just redesigned, and it is what I'll be primarily porting to WordPress.  They also have a WordPress blog sitting at /blog running an outdated WP with a Kubrick-based theme - they would like to keep that theme/styling.

Here's the issues:

- They want to manage it all from a single backend
- They want the blog with the different look and feel to reside on /blog for the links that are already out there (multisite won't allow this).
- The blog pages should all be consistent - categories, single posts, archives, etc
- Search should return results from both site and blog

So basically, I'm wondering if this is feasible from a single install with conditional statements and theming, or if a multisite is necessary (and all the hassles that come with it).  Normally I would just go multisite because of the separate theming, but since the blog that has the separate theme needs to sit on /blog, that won't work (easily).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* go with multisite, but as long as they're only asking for a different look and feel, you could work it out with Templates and conditional statements for enqueueing styles, scripts, etc.

For the ease of things, I'd go with a single site install.

Comment: I've been trying to drill down if there's anything else they want out of that blog section other than a different look and feel, but it doesn't seem so.  My only concern there is `archive.php`, but perhaps I can override those related pages and avoid sending people to the generic archive altogether.

Comment: Just alter the query. Remember: You can always use conditionals with the `posts_clauses` filter. Benefit: Don't add an additional query.

Comment: There's not a whole lot of info on `posts_clauses` out there - it's basically adding multiple additional SQL statements to the query object, right?

Comment: Oh, there is. Just search for the filter name and my user name. I'm a big fan of that one :)

And no, it's not adding anything. It gives you the query in pieces. You can then add, alter, whatever-you-can-imagine with the query.

Comment: If you've got time at some point, can you add page for `post_clauses` on the Codex? You've got a lot of info on here that would be nice to have collected there.

Comment: Do you have a link to the empty page?

Comment: Absolutely - http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_clauses

Comment: Done. See [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_clauses) now... :)